# javascript page load position

Tags: javascript, html

We moved an old site to a new server for hosting purposes before we build a new site.

Once moved the site now loads at the bottom of the page. I've tried all sorts of adjustments to the javascript and html but I'm at a loss to what is causing it to load at the bottom. Any help in identifying the problem would be greatly appreciated...

**Current site location:**
http://eversighthosting.info/artstow/Artspg1.htm

**The page code:**

```
<script language="javascript">
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} else {
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0',
        'width', '100%',
        'height', '100%',
        'src', 'Arts',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        'align', 'middle',
        'play', 'true',
        'loop', 'true',
        'scale', 'showall',
        'wmode', 'window',
        'devicefont', 'false',
        'id', 'Arts',
        'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
        'name', 'Arts',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
        'movie', 'Arts',
        'salign', ''
        ); //end AC code
}
</script><embed src="Artspg1_files/Arts.swf" quality="high"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" play="true"
loop="true" scale="showall" wmode="window" devicefont="false"   bgcolor="#ffffff"
name="Arts" menu="true" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain"
salign="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" align="middle" height="100%"
width="100%"> 
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"    
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash
swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="Arts"
align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="movie" value="Arts.swf" /><param name="quality"
value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> <embed
src="Arts.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%"
height="100%" name="Arts" align="middle"
allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
</noscript>
```

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using Flash anymore. I'd recommend you to port the legacy Flash code to something modern like HTML5, which will work on every modern browser and operating system.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This is a very old side and it's only in use while a completely new site is being built.

Answer (score 0):

The direct reason, though I can't go so far as to explain why this is, is that Arts.swf appears twice in the page. The higher, blank version appears to originate from the `<noscript>` tag, although I don't really have an idea of why that's being loaded instead of ignored on a JS-capable browser. I would be pretty surprised if any browsers running without JavaScript have flash loaded, so I would just take that content out and replace it with a warning that says "You need Flash to view this site"

Comment: Katana314, Thank you for your reply. I changed the script by commenting out as follows with no change in the page load or function.
Commented out from the first </script><!--<embed src="Artspg1_files/Arts.swf" until the second embed src="Artspg1_files/Arts.swf"